# Initialization Vector reuse in ext4 filename encryption

Tags: filesystems, encryption, disk-encryption, cryptography

The [fscrypt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/fscrypt.rst) document says:

> Because of the requirements to retain support for efficient directory lookups and filenames of up to 255 bytes, the same IV is used for every filename in a directory.

Questions:

1. What is this [Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) ('IV') that is being reused? Where is it stored in the directory?
2. This sentence explaining the reason of IV reuse is vague. Aren't there other solutions, for example, using a synthetic IV computed from filenames?